# Boxplot color grouping in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I have 9 boxplots organized in 3 groups:

1. A1,B1,C1
2. A2,B2,C2
3. A3,B3,C3

How is it possible with `seaborn` to plot all A in red, all B in green, and all C in blue?

I create boxplots with `bplot = sns.boxplot(data=[d for d in data], width=0.5)` and am aware of the existence of `bplot.artists`. Could anyone provide a hint on this?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
for a in row:
    for b in column:
        if box in left:
            graph with color 'red'
        elif box in middle:
            graph with color 'green'
        elif box in right:
            graph with color 'blue'
        else:
          'no color'
```

Basically, I am `for` looping using nested loops and inside them is a `if/else` algorithm (or whatever you call it). If it is in the top column, paint it red. If it is in the bottom column, paint it blue. If it is in the middle column, paint it green. Else, paint it with no color. This should give you a rough estimate of what you need. It can be easily expandable by adding in another color. It is extensible to N rows and M columns.

Answer (score -1):

color is an optional parameter that gets passed into the underlying matplotlib object so just specify it in the initialization parameters: `sns.boxplot(data, color='blue')` and use a for loop to hit A, B, and C

Comment: Can you note that the 9 boxplots are organized in 3 groups? It's not A1,A2,A3/B1,B2,B3/C1,C2,C3 but it is A1,B1,C1/A2,B2,C2/A3,B3,C3?

Comment: Yes. I agree with @Employee. In fact it doesn't matter because it's strictly in the OP's boxplot groups. A1, B1 and C1 not A1, A2 and A3.